# UIWebView windows authentication in swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I have a problem with the UIWebView. I cant open a Website with Windows Authentication... In the Safari Browser a pop-up appears, therefor in the WebView Control happened nothing.

Can someone help me with this problem?

Here my code

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        webView.delegate = self;

        let url = NSURL (string: "http://test.raphaels.com/mobile/");
        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }
}
```

This piece code of works perfectly fine on non-secure server(URL) on iOS simulator, thats iPhone simulator/emulator on Xcode. But when I use the above URL(can only be accessed from intranet). It asks for username/password in browser and stops in iPhone emulator. Please help me, how can i supply username and password. I searched on internet and found many examples, unfortunately none of them was in swift programming.

I tried to write a solution which fails, so below is the failing code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    webView.delegate = self;


    let username = "username11";
    let password = "password22";
    let loginString = NSString(format: "%@:%@", username, password);
    let loginData: NSData = loginString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!;
    let base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil);

    // create the request
    let url = NSURL (string: "http://test.raphaels.com/mobile/");
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("Basic \(base64LoginString)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")




    webView.loadRequest(request);
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to have the url to have two http's in it?  Also, NSURL(string:_) returns an optional NSURL, you should probably have to unwrap it before using it to make an NSMutableURLRequest.

Comment: two https ? Its just one URL. Have you seen before, when you browse some secure URL then there is a username/password javascript kind of alert, if not filled or filled incorrectly then access is denied with 401 Error code.

Comment: Sure.  However I have never seen a url with two "http://" substrings in it.
your let url = NSURL(string: "http://"+"http://...")
//sorry stackoverflow keeps doing some formatting on things that look like urls

Comment: How can I unwrap ? I am new to swift, iOS all. I wrote an application in java and using the existing codebase to point to my web app.

Comment: Oh, does your compiler warn you "Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!' or '?' " on the NSMutableURLRequest line?

Comment: yes compiler asked to put ! and it was a typo with two https.

Answer (score 6):

And it worked :-) With below piece of code.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();

        webView.delegate = self;

        let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(string: "http://test.raphaels.com/mobile/");
        urlComponents.user = "username11";
        urlComponents.password = "password22";

        let url = urlComponents.URL;

        let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        webView.loadRequest(requestObj);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Objective C version

```
NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithString:@"http://test.raphaels.com/mobile/"];

[urlComponents setUser:@"username11"];
[urlComponents setPassword:@"password22"];

NSURL *url = [urlComponents URL];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and easy solution is: use URL as

```
http://username:password@test.raphaels.com/mobile/
```

No need for any special code.